# Windows Defender to find localization numeric value for Reporting

Tags: ssrs-2008, windows-defender

i need to create some SSRS reports For Windows Defender .. i need to find localization numeric values for Detection source

```
    Detection Source: <Detection source> for example:
User: user initiated
System: system initiated
Real-time: real-time component initiated
IOAV: IE Downloads and Outlook Express Attachments initiated
NIS: Network inspection system
IEPROTECT: IE - IExtensionValidation; this protects against malicious webpage controls
Early Launch Antimalware (ELAM). This includes malware detected by the boot sequence
Remote attestation
```

Reference link [enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-antivirus/troubleshoot-windows-defender-antivirus)
i need to select in case so i need to know numeric values for each of option.
one thing is can use

```
SrsResources.Localization.GetString(Choose(Fields!DetectionSource.Value,"DetectionByUser","System","Realtime","IOAV","NIS","BHO","ELAM","LocalAttestation","RemoteAttestation","AMSI","UAC"), User!Language)
```

but then i dont have acces to Visual Studio as iam database person.. so cant create DLL and include in reference of report.

Please help me out how to find numeric values to each one of these.

Answer (score -1):

From the statement `SrsResources.Localization.GetString`, I am guessing that you're using SCCM since that exact statement is part of the SCCM report:

> Endpoint Protection -> Endpoint Protection - Hidden -> Computer malware list

If that's the case, then just copy the report and change what you need and the function will work.

Because in the report properties the `srsresources.dll` is referenced as `SrsResources, culture=neutral`, the dll is needed in order to translate the value to the correct name in the language the user running the report is using.

If you're just interested in the numeric values behind each entry, however, then it is just a list starting with one. Meaning:

1. "DetectionByUser",
2. “System",
3. “Realtime",
4. “IOAV",
5. "NIS",
6. "BHO",
7. "ELAM",
8. “LocalAttestation",
9. "RemoteAttestation",
10. "AMSI",
11. "UAC"